# Bootstrap inline search form is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

bootstrap inline search form created .

check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/brm5zts3/

But i need to use bootstrap  class to replace the drop down something like

http://bootsnipp.com/iframe/rg72r

I tried below code

```
<div class="input-group-btn input-group-select">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
<span class="concept">com</span> <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li><a href="com">com</a></li>
<li><a href="net">net</a></li>
<li><a href="org">org</a></li>
<li><a href="biz">biz</a></li>
<li><a href="name">name</a></li>
<li><a href="us">us</a></li>
</ul>
<input type="hidden" class="input-group-select-val" name="tld[]['type'][]" value="com">
</div>
```

INSTEAD OF existing one

```
<select class="inputbox" name="tld[]">
<option selected="" value="com">com</option>
<option value="net">net</option>
<option value="org">org</option>
<option value="biz">biz</option>
<option value="name">name</option>
<option value="us">us</option>
</select>
```

But search is not working

The following image will tell you what i need.

imgur.com/XD5QVTE

Comment: There is no problem with your code! the problem is with css file u imported!

Comment: You're missing the `input-group` class on your wrapper element.The `input-group-btn` is suppose to be on the button element or form-control.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

View the snippet in full screen to see the form inlined. 
Your problem was that you placed everything in a table when it didn't need to be in the table.

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-inline" name="lookup" method="post" action="#">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="check_availability">
<input type="hidden" name="showrelated" value="true">

    <div class="form-group">
    <input name="txtDomainName" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" size="24" maxlength="60">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select  class="form-control input-lg" name="tld[]">
       <option selected="" value="com">com</option>
<option value="net">net</option>
<option value="org">org</option>
<option value="biz">biz</option>
<option value="name">name</option>
<option value="us">us</option>
<option value="info">info</option>
<option value="in">in</option>
<option value="co.in">co.in</option>
<option value="net.in">net.in</option>
<option value="org.in">org.in</option>
<option value="firm.in">firm.in</option>
<option value="gen.in">gen.in</option>
<option value="ind.in">ind.in</option>
<option value="eu">eu</option>
<option value="mobi">.mobi</option>
<option value="mn">.mn</option>
<option value="bz">.bz</option>
<option value="cc">.cc</option>
<option value="tv">.tv</option>
<option value="eu.com">eu.com</option>
<option value="gb.com">gb.com</option>
<option value="ae.org">ae.org</option>
<option value="kr.com">kr.com</option>
<option value="us.com">us.com</option>
<option value="qc.com">qc.com</option>
<option value="de.com">de.com</option>
<option value="gb.net">gb.net</option>
<option value="no.com">no.com</option>
<option value="hu.com">hu.com</option>
<option value="jpn.com">jpn.com</option>
<option value="uy.com">uy.com</option>
<option value="za.com">za.com</option>
<option value="br.com">br.com</option>
<option value="cn.com">cn.com</option>
<option value="sa.com">sa.com</option>
<option value="se.com">se.com</option>
<option value="se.net">se.net</option>
<option value="uk.com">uk.com</option>
<option value="uk.net">uk.net</option>
<option value="ru.com">ru.com</option>
<option value="ws">ws</option>
<option value="co.uk">co.uk</option>
<option value="org.uk">org.uk</option>
<option value="me.uk">me.uk</option> 
        
      </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Search!</button>
    
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old question but putting my 2 lines in case you have not found a solution yet.

2 ways of doing it and both need specific JS

1st way is to CSS transform the select/option values which can not be done through pure CSS but needs JS. use [Bootstrap Select JS](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) for that.

2nd way is how it is implemented at the bootsnipp you provided. If you check you will see he has some javascript that changes the actualy hidden field input into the one he selected from the list of ul tag.